# Devise and mailers - How to get current URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mailer

When sending emails (for example for 'Reset password instructions') using Devise, i need to know current domain URL, and set that value into mailer's template.

request.url doesn't work for me.

Assuming, this Rails application is accessibly from multiple URLs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Request object is not available in the mailers. You will need to set up the host in the environment configuration file with something like:

`ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = 'myhost.com'`

Comment: This Rails application is accessible from multiple URLs. This way i need a 'dynamic' URL

Comment: In that case you will have to manually get the domain name from the request, pass it to the mailer object as a parameter, and use it with the url helpers as detailed on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views

Comment: As eugen said you will need to get the address from the request. Check the whole request object. Perhaps the information you are looking for is in request.env, and then pass it to the template.